# a way to deduplicate output of a grep command?

Tags: linux, grep

i have a command like this :

```
  <command linux> | grep <myfilter>
```

and my output is :

```
  exact-same-line-4-times
  exact-same-line-4-times
  exact-same-line-4-times
  exact-same-line-4-times
```

is there a way to deduplicate output to have only 1 item?

```
  exact-same-line-4-times
```

Comment: Kindly do add your attempted code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: sooooo `| uniq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified much about your usecase. In you oversimplified example the "filter" matches always the same line, and never a different one. If that's the case, maybe piping the result into `uniq` could be enough:

```sh
echo -e 'one\ntwo\ntwo\ntwo\nthree' | grep two | uniq
two
```

However, if the pattern matches different lines, the solution above can behave like this

```sh
echo -e 'one\ntwo\ntwo\ntwo\nthree\ntwo' | grep t | uniq
two
three
two
```

printing `two` twice because something else matched in between. If you don't like that, then maybe you want to `sort` before `uniq`, or just `sort -u`:

```sh
echo -e 'one\ntwo\ntwo\ntwo\nthree\ntwo' | grep t | sort -u
three
two
```